# field validation for other field is not null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 2 fields price and currency.I want to make dependency validation if price!=null currency field is required and if currency!=null price field is required as well as I want to check price field is numeric.
if both field is null and that both field is not required.I want to validate in laravel 5.3

```
$this->validate($request,[
  'price'=>'numeric',
  'price'=>'required_if:currency,nullable',
  'currency'=>'required_if:price,not nullable',
]);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `required_with` for this.

```
$this->validate($request,[
  'price'=>'required_with:currency|numeric',
  'currency'=>'required_with:price',
]);
```